# aeron 1.37 pingpong(c) test gets a slightly higher latency number compare to 1.31.2

Tags: c++, c, aeron

I've been using real-logic/Aeron(c/c++ version) for almost 2 years.
Recently I was thinking of upgrading Aeron from 1.31.2 to 1.37.0.
But after run the pingpong test, I got a slightly higher latency number(around 0.1 us rtt) from 1.37.0.
I ran the Ping on one server, and Pong on another server.
I tested version by version (from 1.31.2 to 1.37.0). all the hardware and how I ran the pingpong are exactly the same, the only differences is the Aeron version.
Here are the latency number(warmup 10,000, message 1,000,000):

- 1.31.2  -> 7.4452 mean us rtt
- 1.32.0  -> 7.4886 mean us rtt
- 1.33.0  -> 7.5054 mean us rtt
- 1.34.0  -> 7.5145 mean us rtt
- 1.35.0  -> 7.5459 mean us rtt
- 1.36.0  -> 7.5297 mean us rtt
- 1.37.0  -> 7.5462 mean us rtt

Anybody knows if I did something wrong, or has anyone experienced the same thing?
is it possible to upgrade the version to 1.37.0 and keep latency number as good as 1.31.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aeron 1.38.2 has some significant changes which improve the performance.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much for replying to me.  will take a look at the new version.